# Windows 7 UAC prompt password caching (Linux-like)

Tags: administrator, uac

If you run lot of applications that requires Admin proviledges you are forced to re-enter the password over and over.
Is it possible to set a (timed) caching of the Administrator password in Windows 7, just like sudo on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of, but you could add your user account to the Administrators group, then the UAC prompt simply requires you to click **Yes** or **No**.  The reason you are being asked for the Administrator's password is that your user account is not a member of group Administrators.

Comment: is there any security risk adding my user account into the Administrators group? (ie. programs elevating without asking consent)

Comment: If you have your UAC slider setting all the way at the top (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975787 for instructions), then all elevation requires you to acknowledge a UAC prompt, so programs can't elevate without your consent.

Comment: Also, malicious programs cannot programmatically click the `Yes` button on a UAC prompt, because the UAC prompt is displayed on a different logical desktop, and window messages are not delivered between desktops.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge, but unless you're not locking your computer whenever you step away from it (bad!), lowering the UAC level such that it only requires you to click 'Ok' instead of typing your full password shouldn't be a serious loss of security, and will ease up on the pain of launching lots of programs which require administrative access.

Not sure what your environment's (work, school, academic, home) security policy is though.

Comment: He should not lower his UAC level.  He is being asked for the Administrator password in the UAC prompt because his user account is not a member of group Administrators.  If he adds his account to that group, the UAC prompt will just have Yes/No buttons on it — no password required.